# Where to find "javascript" source code of V8 DOM method implementations (document.createElement())?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, v8

I need to rewrite document.createElement() method and I'm looking for a javascript source code online to get some ideas. I searched http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse but it seems like the search returns results from all svn sources (even non-related libraries) which makes it messy. I browsed the code in the svn, and there are of course C++ source code, but obviously no javascript implementations.

Comment: Such a thing is not possible. If you `alert` or `console.log` this or any other native function you will see something like `function name() { [native code] }`

Comment: _"I need to rewrite document.createElement()"_ - Why? _"but obviously no javascript implementations"_ - You can't just rewrite a native DOM method because you can only interact with the DOM via the methods the browser provides (unless you write your own browser). You _can_ write a wrapper method that calls the built-in DOM methods...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to implement DOMNodeInserted event for IE.

Comment: nnnnnn you CAN rewrite any DOM method that it's "writable" property is set to true. Could you explain a bit about the wrapper method?

Comment: DOMNodeInserted is slated for deprecation, so you won't be writing this for only IE....

Comment: It's not yet depreciated, but will be soon, so that's correct I'll use it for other browsers too...

Comment: _"you CAN rewrite any DOM method that it's "writable" property is set to true"_ - I meant (and indeed said) that your replacement method couldn't interact with the DOM unless you call the browser's built-in DOM methods (or in the case where you've overwritten a built-in method you might need to keep a reference to the original first). By "wrapper" I meant `function myCreateElement(some params here) { /* some code here that does some stuff and then calls document.createElement() and then possible does more stuff */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not, and usually cannot, re-write native DOM methods. Methods such as `createElement` are "close to the surface" of a client's EMACscript implementation, have protected scopes, and are simply not able to be reproduced by "userland" script.

In the case of `createElement`, you might be able to overwrite the `createElement` function of the `document` object in certain browsers (see below), but you'll also quickly find that it crashes and burns on certain existing clients/versions. Further, you cannot change the prototype of `document` because it has none.

You can, however, **easily** and without risk create a small wrapper function:

```
var createElement = function (ele_type, attrs) {
    var ele = document.createElement(ele_type);
    if (!ele)
        return false;

    for (var idx in attrs) {
        if ((idx == 'styles' || idx == 'style') && typeof attrs[idx] == 'object') {
            for (var prop in attrs[idx]){ele.style[prop] = attrs[idx][prop]}
        } else if (idx == 'html') {
            ele.innerHTML = attrs[idx]
        } else {
            ele.setAttribute(idx, attrs[idx]);
        }
    }

    // now fire any custom events or do whatever you needed to do

};

var myNewDiv = createElement ('div', {'id':'myNewDiv', 'styles':{'color':'red'}});
```

That gives you the opportunity to implement custom code upon creation of a new element. It will work on all browsers regardless of implementation differences, and is as future-proof as any other code you would write today.

Another route mentioned above, which is NOT cross-browser or guaranteed to work even tomorrow, is to overwrite the `createElement` function of active `document` instance. The trouble with this approach is that the document object isn't defined by the specification -- it is implementation specific. *Today*, Firefox (for example) will allow you to overwrite this function, but that could change without notice.

```
document.createElement = function(originalDocumentCreate) {
    return function() {
        var ele = originalDocumentCreate.apply(this, arguments);

        // now fire any custom events or do whatever you needed to do

        return ele;
    };
}(document.createElement);
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11727842/610573 *(code concept credit to Esailija)*

Comment: I'm just curious: How crazy/compatible would it be to "extend" `document.createElement`. Like so: `var nativeMethod = document.createElement;` and then `document.createElement = function(ele_type, attrs) { nativeMethod.call(document, ele_type, attrs); /* Then do other stuff */ })`. Works in Chrome, via the dev console anyway.

Comment: @meetamit Chrome plays nice.  I hear that (older versions?) of MSIE (surprise surprise) don't.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But wrapping won't work in my case, simply because I have no control to force users to use this wrapper function to create new elements, and in fact this is the main reason I need to rewrite the native code so users can continue creating elements with the "native" code, and I can add functionality to it.

Comment: @meetamit You can get away with it in Firefox and Chrome **today**. The specification does NOT dictate, however, that this is the case. The `document` object contains many implementation-specific quirks and is not predictable or trustworthy.