# Hook canvas's toDataURL

Tags: javascript, canvas, hook, todataurl

[**EDIT**] I should have been more specific (thanks for the response Below the Radar!). I'd like the trigger to console.log to capture the returned URI when the object calls `toDataURL`. In the linked jsfiddle, the object calling `toDataURL` is `canvas`. This may be a sticking point, because I may need to capture the calling object as well? I could accomplish what I want by simply encapsulating `canvas.toDataURL()` in a console.log statement, but I'd like this to be more dynamic than that---which led me to think of adding a hook on `toDataURL`

jsFiddle, update: https://jsfiddle.net/spe4q1d8/170/

---

I'm trying to create a hook that I could place at the top or bottom of a JavaScript file which would trigger `console.log` every time a specific function is called. The particular function I want to hook is `toDataURL()` [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).

I've been able to set up a hook on something like `alert` or `console.log` itself, but can't figure out how to hook `toDataURL`.

**jsFiddle**, hook on `alert` and hook on `document.createElement()`

- https://jsfiddle.net/spe4q1d8/142/

**References**

- [Hooking document.createElement using function prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727759/hooking-document-createelement-using-function-prototype)
- [Need to hook into a javascript function call, any way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273309/need-to-hook-into-a-javascript-function-call-any-way-to-do-this)
- https://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2012/1/12/Adding-custom-callbacks-to-existing-JavaScript-functions

Comment: ok see my edited answer. (btw, you should have commented my answer because I did not received an alert when you edited your question ;)

Comment: :) finished test ==> https://jsfiddle.net/81kgbmnx/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extend the prototyped function for instance:

```
var toDataURL = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL;
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL = function(type, encoderOptions) {
  var uri = toDataURL.call(this, type, encoderOptions);
  console.log(uri);
  return uri;
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.toDataURL()
```