# How to create listener on document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document, createelement

How to create listener on document.createElement func?

For example, after

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```

it was done automatically

```
console.log("createElement worked")
```

P.S. how to do the same but with different functions, for example toDataURL

```
var str = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

it was done automatically

```
console.log("toDataURL worked")
```

Comment: `const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.append(cvs);
cvs.addEventListener("click", function(e) { console.log("X")})`

Comment: You need to show more code. Nothing is done automatically

Comment: console.log("createElement worked") // it can't be show automatically . you must have used it somewhere in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the original function and add your desired code extension at the beginning.

```
document.createElement = function (create) {
    return function() {
        console.log ('element created');
        return create.apply (this, arguments);
    };
}(document.createElement)
```

Example adapted from [Hooking document.createElement using function prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727759/hooking-document-createelement-using-function-prototype)